# php show data from db

Tags: php, mysqli, show

I'm trying to show data from my first row of db in a html page..
this is: index.html I don't understand where is wrong..

```
<div class="container">

  <h3>Menu del giorno <?php $currentDate = date("d-m-Y"); echo $currentDate;?></h3><br/>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mydb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menu");


  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Cucina:</strong></p><br/><br/>";
  echo "<p>Primi</p><br/>";
  echo "<p>" . $row['piatto1'] . "</p><br/>";
  echo "<p>" . $row['piatto2'] . "</p><br/><br/>";
  echo "<p>Secondo</p><br/>";
  echo "<p>" . $row['secondo'] . "</p><br/>";

  }
  mysqli_close($con);
  ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Ah, the menu of the day.

Comment: Risposta: Change the extension from `index.html` to `index.php` that's the problem. Unless you've instructed Apache treat `.html` files as PHP.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: Your file name is index.html or index.php ?
Please send result of script here for better helps.
Regards.

Comment: Then add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Take it up with the guys who gave you "answers" then. They'll need to work for their points ;-)

Comment: So, you're sure that you're not getting any errors. *Hm...* that's not what my server said.

Comment: This `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` by the way, needs to be wrapped inside PHP tags and not just on its own like that. `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); ?>` - The reason why you're not getting any errors thrown back. You'll learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your extension is wrong. It should, as other users have indicated, be titled index.php instead of index.html.

Second, you might not be running this on a server. PHP is server side, meaning the code is executed before the user gets it, which is what makes it secure. The downside is that, unlike client-side things like javascript that operate/execute in the browser itself, for PHP you will need an actual server.

If you aren't already uploading (with an FTP for example) to a server that supports PHP, you will have to make one yourself. An example for mac: [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/).

That will also support your SQL DB. Hope this helped!

EDIT: Oh, I see a new error. When you have a quotation mark within a quotation mark, you need an escape sequence (" \" hello\" "). Otherwise PHP will think the second " is ending the first, instead of actually being in the string. So you should have, for example:

```
echo "<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><strong>Cucina:</strong></p><br/><br/>";
```

Comment: i'm on php server.. I upload the file with filezilla..

Comment: Oh, I see a new error.
When you have a quotation mark within a quotation mark, you need an escape sequence (" \" hello\" "). Otherwise PHP will think the second " is ending the first, instead of actually being in the string.

So you should have, for example:


>echo "<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><strong>Cucina:</strong></p><br/><br/>";

Comment: Finally, someone who's paying attention.

Comment: Fred you're unprofessional. I'm new to php.. it may be that I'm missing something right? 
thank a lot @djbhindi!!

Comment: I'm done with answering questions like this. You of all people should know this type of stuff if you're going to become a developer. @user3699353 If you can't put 2 and 2 together, then you're in the wrong industry. I don't get "paid" for answering here. I figured it out way before this answer was given. You should have enabled error reporting in the first place which would have signaled the **parse error.**

Comment: No problem :). Hope it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your file from `index.html` to `index.php`.

A HTML file should only contain valid HTML code, where PHP files can contain PHP code statements and are interpreted by your PHP binary (e.g. `php.exe` on Windows). If you put PHP code in a HTML file this code won't be interpreted. So the PHP code is either way displayed as plain text in your browser, or - in worse case - will invalidate your HTML code. And thus may be block displaying of your page.

(You can instruct your webserver (e.g. Apache) to treat `.html` files as PHP files. But I don't think this is the case here.)

Comment: As said [`2 minutes before`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025349/php-show-data-from-db#comment37034463_24025349) ;-) on both counts.

Comment: The plot thickens as it were. Read the OP's (*latest*) comments. All the reasons why I don't post answers for questions like this. Live and learn, I always say. ;-)